# Обновление страницы c задержкой

Tags: javascript, html

Для возврата на предыдущую страницу у меня заготовлена кнопка:

```
<input class="buttonSend" onclick="window.history.back();" type="button" value="Вернуться назад"/>
```

Как после выполнения возврата обновить страницу на которую я вернулась? 
Я пробовала дописать так:

```
echo "<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>window.location.replace('http://homka/mypage/index.php')</script>";
```

Но обновление происходит моментально, не выходя на страницу, где у меня содержится информация о выполнение скрипта и кнопка "Вернуться назад".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Вариант №1 (JS)**

```
echo '<script>SetTimeout(function(){ window.location.replace("http://homka/mypage/index.php"); }, 1000);</script>';
```

*1000* - это 1 секунда в миллисекундах. После 1 секунду страница обновится.

**Вариант №2 (HTML)**

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="10; URL=http://homka/mypage/index.php">';
```

Работает аналогично первому варианту, но здесь(в `content`) указываются не миллисекунды, а секунды.

Comment: Спасибо! Это работает. Но я вот пытаюсь добиться следующего: на странице №1 (../index.php) я формирую список на удаление, нажимаю кнопку "Удалить" и у меня в фоновом режиме выполняется скрипт, а пользователя выкидывает на новую страницу №2 (.../delete.php), где содержится информация об удаленных объектах. Вот именно на второй странице у меня кнопка "Вернуться назад". Я возвращаюсь и страницу №1 надо автоматически обновить. Если же я вернусь назад по кнопке, то ваш код не сработает. А если ваш код вставлю в скрипт №1, то это бред, т.к. исходная страница будет обновляться всё время. @mix

Comment: По одной кнопке 2 инструкции я выполнить не могу за одно обращение (верно?), поэтому мне надо сделать какое-то событие, что если я вернулась по событию "Вернуться назад" на страницу №1, то обновить страницу №1. Я так представляю, но что-то не представляю как мне это воплотить в реальность. @mix

Comment: @Юленька раз вы заговорили о бреде, то скажу, что ваш скрипт бредово написан(личное мнение), поскольку нельзя так делать. Нужно иметь части front и back, тогда таких проблем не будет. P.S. Поскольку такая ситуация, то могу посоветовать заменить `onclick="window.history.back();"` на страницу с формированием статичной ссылки. Тогда все будет работать.

Comment: Да я же не про ваш код, а то, что моя страница будет обновляться и обновляться. У меня бред.) Я не хотела вас обидеть. Некорректно выразилась. Ваша идея мне очень нравится. Я может таймер добавлю, типа "Возврат на предыдущую страницу произойдет ** сек." А то, что у меня бредово всё написано - я знаю. Просто я только учусь. @mix